# Clone request headers in Vanilla Perl CGI to LWP UserAgent

Tags: perl, cgi, header, lwp-useragent, request-headers

I have a perl CGI application that I want to take the users request headers, and turn those around into an LWP::UserAgent get request.  Basically the goal is to replicate the incoming users headers and use those to make a separate request.

I've tried to create the headers myself but when I attempt to display the CGI headers and then my clone UserAgent headers, they aren't exactly the same.  Here's what I got:

```
my $cgi = new CGI;
my %headers = map { $_ => $cgi->http($_) } $cgi->http;
my $req_headers = HTTP::Headers->new( %headers );
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( default_headers => $req_headers );
print Dumper $ua->default_headers;
```

Basically, %headers and $ua->default_headers are not identical.  $ua->default_headers has an agent that identifies itself as a perl script.  I can manually set $ua->agent("") but there are other imperfections and the headers still aren't identical.

What's the best way to do what I want?  There's got to be an easier solution...

Comment: I don't understand your question. The HTTP headers aren't available to a CGI script. The HTTP headers are parsed into environment variables and sent to the CGI script after filtering. Also, CGI doesn't seem to have a documented method `http`, and the second line looks like it is missing a `map`.

Comment: Maybe I'm not phrasing my question correctly... http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/LDS/CGI.pm-3.49/cgi_docs.html Search for "->http".  That gives me a list of the request headers, does it not?   Also see http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=838453

Comment: Did you see Kinopiko's comment about using the keyword `map` on line 2?

Comment: @Kinopiko,mobrule - Apologies, I didn't do a direct copy/paste of my code. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the problem has to do with naming of incoming http headers compared to what HTTP::Headers uses.

The incoming parameters all have `HTTP_` prefix in them where HTTP::Headers doesn't use that naming convention (which makes sense). Plus it looks like (a quick read in the code) that HTTP::Headers does the right thing in converting '-' into '_' for its own use.

I would recommended changing your `map` to following that removes the prefix:

```
# remove leading HTTP_ from keys, note: this assumes all keys have pattern
# HTTP_*
%headers = map { ( /^HTTP_(.*?)$/ ) => $cgi->http($_) } $cgi->http;
```

Here is the debugging script I used:

```
my $cgi = CGI->new;
my %headers = map { $_ => $cgi->http($_) } $cgi->http;
my $req_headers = HTTP::Headers->new( %headers );
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( default_headers => $req_headers );

print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";
print Dumper($ua->default_headers);
print Dumper( \%headers );

# remove HTTP_ from $_
%headers = map { ( /^HTTP_(.*?)$/ ) => $cgi->http($_) } $cgi->http;
$req_headers = HTTP::Headers->new( %headers );
$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( default_headers => $req_headers );

print "headers part deux:\n";
print Dumper( $ua );
```

Hope that Helps

Comment: funny just noticed that this is over a year old, hope it helps someone else :)